# iText, Reduce a mono-spaced font's pitch

Tags: itext

Trying to reduce a mono-spaced(FontFactory.COURIER) font's pitch i.e reduce the spacing between the letters. Could not locate the method in the API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Chunk#setCharacterSpacing, or PdfContentByte#setCharacterSpacing. It is not a property of a font instance.

Comment: @AlexeySubach If you make your comment an answer, it can be accepted, and we can up-vote it.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, done. Thank you. Just wasn't sure, thought you might have some duplicates in mind.

Comment: @AlexeySubach I don't know if this is a duplicate question. I don't remember adding it to [The Best iText Questions on Stack Overflow](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions). That doesn't mean the question wasn't answered on Stack Overflow before, but that the answer is hard to find if it is ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Chunk#setCharacterSp‌​acing` or `PdfContentByte#setCh‌​aracterSpacing`, depending on your context.

Negative `charSpacing` values will decrease spacing between letters, positive ones will increase it.

Example from Bruno's book (slightly modified):

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(text, font1);

// reduce spacing
chunk.setCharacterSpacing(-0.5f);
document.add(new Paragraph(chunk));

// usual spacing
chunk = new Chunk(text, font1);
document.add(new Paragraph(chunk));
```

What you will get will look similar to this:

[image: Result]

As you see, the first line has reduced char spacing, whereas the second one has regular spacing.